# Opendaylight: how to get MAC address of switch from datapath ID?

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am developing an application for opendaylight Carbon where I need to know the MAC address of the switch. Can I determine this from the DpnId when the switch connects? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DPID uniquely identifies the switch. The MAC address is generally not exposed.
Moreover, the switch itself generally does not have a MAC address 
(they may have tens of MAC addresses for different functions/interfaces).
Switches work at a lower level, though, they work with MAC addresses.

Comment: I was thinking it might be relevant for LLDP.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which MAC you are referring to. If you are referring MAC address of each ofport of the DPN then you can register listener for `FlowCapableNodeConnector` model and you can get MAC by calling `FlowCapableNodeConnector#getHardwareAddress` in add method of listener. And if you are talking about VM/packet Source/destination MAC, then you first you need to punt the packet to controller and then you can use `PacketProcessingListener`  and extract MAC as shown below.

```
public void onPacketReceived(PacketReceived notification) {

   final short tableId = notification.getTableId().getValue();
   final byte[] data = notification.getPayload();
   Ethernet res = new Ethernet();

    try {
        res.deserialize(data, 0, data.length * NetUtils.NumBitsInAByte);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("PacketInHandler: Failed to decode Packet ", e);
        return;
    }
    try {
        Packet pkt = res.getPayload();
        LOG.info("Packet type is ->{}", pkt.getClass().getName());
        if (pkt instanceof IPv4) {
            IPv4 ipv4 = (IPv4) pkt;
            byte[] srcMac = res.getSourceMACAddress();
            byte[] dstMac = res.getDestinationMACAddress();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I needed this for another piece of code I'm writing so thanks for posting this.